# I'm looking for a SPARQL query program

Tags: c#, recommendation-engine, sparql

I have various sparql queries that i'd like to test. Is there a website or simple programm that allows me to test these queries?

I dont want a [validator like this one](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html), but I'd like to really execute the query and get a result.

Comment: I have edited my answer to add a note on `roqet` a tool that might do what you need. Not C# though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed above you might see if a provider has given a web interface over their SPARQL endpoint. They normaly do e.g. [Dbpedia](http://api.talis.com/stores/bbc-demo/items/sparql/spared.html),[BBC Backstage](http://api.talis.com/stores/bbc-demo/items/sparql/spared.html) etc.

For a tool that allows you to enter an arbitrary endpoint so you can query it you might want to check [Twinkle](http://www.ldodds.com/projects/twinkle/). It's the only program that I know that does this.

Comment: If @Roflcoptr wants to query its own data then `Twinkle` is definitely the program he might be looking for. (+1)

Comment: what about `roqet` ? I just remembered it existed ;)

Answer (score 2):

A very common one is [DBPEDIA SPARQL end point](http://dbpedia.org/sparql). Dbpedia contains the info boxes from Wikipedia in RDF format and offers an SPARQL endpoint to query that data.

Try also the LOD cache from Openlink Software at http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql. It contains a subset of the famous [Linked Data Cloud](http://linkeddata.org/).

Another quite good also to test some queries is the UK Government Education database. See [SPARQLing data.gov.uk: Edubase Data](http://blogs.talis.com/n2/archives/818).

All these links will lead to Web based forms where you can input your queries.

If you tell us what type of queries you're running we might be able to advice better.

**Edit: to add a note on roqet tool**

A program to directly test SPARQL queries with your own data ... `roqet` from [Redland libraries](http://librdf.org/). You can do things like ...

```
roqet -Dhttp://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/ 
      -e 'select * where {<http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person> ?p ?v }'
```

or

```
roqet -Dfile://path/to/your/rdf.file 
       -e 'select * where { ?s ?p ?o }'
```

Answer (score 0):

I run a free SPARQL demo site - not an endpoint, it has no data - called Triplr.  You can try it a http://triplr.org/sparql